# "Target is not responding, retrying..." ST LoRaWAN AT_Master/End_Node programms not working on NUCLEO-L073RZ

Tags: embedded, stm32cubeide, nucleo

I've read all topics regarding this error on the forum but nothing helped.
The borad connected to Arduino connector is USI® WM-SG-SM-42.
Projects build succesfully and connect with the board through ST-Link v3. This is the output I get when debugger and low power work is not enabled(set to 0):

STMicroelectronics ST-LINK GDB server. Version 6.0.0
Starting server with the following options:

```
  Persistent Mode          : Disabled
  Logging Level            : 1
  Listen Port Number       : 61234
  Status Refresh Delay     : 15s
  Verbose Mode             : Disabled
  SWD Debug                : Enabled
  InitWhile                : Enabled
```

Waiting for debugger connection...
Debugger connected
Waiting for debugger connection...
Debugger connected
Waiting for debugger connection...

---

```
                 STM32CubeProgrammer v2.9.0-RC01
```

---

ST-LINK SN : 0667FF343339415043031750
ST-LINK FW : V2J39M27
Board     : NUCLEO-L073RZ
Voltage   : 3.26V
SWD freq  : 950 KHz
Connect mode: Under Reset
Reset mode : Hardware reset
Device ID : 0x447
Revision ID : Rev Z
Device name : STM32L07x/L08x/L010
Flash size : 192 KBytes
Device type : MCU
Device CPU : Cortex-M0+
BL Version : --

Memory Programming ...

Opening and parsing file: ST-LINK_GDB_server_a16776.srec

File        : ST-LINK_GDB_server_a16776.srec
Size        : 61876 Bytes
Address     : 0x08000000

Erasing memory corresponding to segment 0:
Erasing internal memory sectors [0 483]

Download in Progress:
File download complete
Time elapsed during download operation: 00:00:05.730

Verifying ...
Download verified successfully

Target is not responding, retrying...
Target is not responding, retrying...
Target is not responding, retrying...
Target is not responding, retrying...
Target is not responding, retrying...
Target is not responding, retrying...
Target is not responding, retrying...
Target is not responding, retrying...
Target is not responding, retrying...
Target is not responding, retrying...
Shutting down...
Exit.

When debugger is enabled console output is the same, without the "Target is not responding, retrying..." part. Program just falls into HAL_PWR_EnterSLEEPMode() or HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode() fuction depending on low_power mode configuration. It stays there forever, which isn't an expected behaviour.
Here is a debugg configuration:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwLyb.png)

debugI ve spend quite a lot of time trying to find the solution and I ve run out of ideas so i will be realy greatefull for help.

Answer (score 0):

I would proceed as follows:

- Make sure that the `GPIO`on the SWD debug interface are initialized correctly. For example if you set them to analog input you will get the exact behavior as you describe. To check if this may be the issue set a breakpoint at the start of the main() function. Does the program stop at this point? If yes, then it is likely. Check the reference manual the pins you want to leave in default configuration are SWCLK and SWIO
- Make sure you have `HAL_DBGMCU_EnableDBGStopMode();` `HAL_DBGMCU_EnableDBGSleepMode();` and `HAL_DBGMCU_EnableDBGStandbyMode();` enabled. Beware, this will at a view micro Amps to your quiescent current
- Check the datashet of your board, make sure all your jumpers are set correctly, maybe your reset line is not connected
- Try debugging with different reset methods as per your provided image, its a drop down in the menu. I believe hardware reset is also possible. I don't think this is the issue as downloading the file works.
- Check that the file your downloading is running on the target by toggeling an LED which is provided on the EVAL board using a GPIO at 1Hz or similar or use a logic analyzer on any of the GPIOs